# Increasing height of single row in table

Tags: tables, height

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Column padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/column-padding-in-tables)

I want to make a table where one column heading has superscript which overlaps with hline above it. How can I increase the height of just that row so that it does not overlap? I tried commands such as `\arraystretch`, but this increases the whole table which then looks odd in the document. The exact code is copied below (MWE).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Some values}
\begin{center}
{
 %\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.35}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c||c|c|c|}
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{c||}{L2 Unit} &  \multicolumn{3}{c|}{SUB} \\ \cline{2-6} 
 Unit & $E^{\text{Dyn}}_{\text{L2}}$&  $P^{\text{SUP}}_{\text{L2}}$ &  Number  &$E^{\text{Dyn}}_{\text{SUB}}$ &$P^{\text{SUP}}_{\text{SUB}}$ \\
Size & (unit) & (unit) &  ($N$) &(unit) & (unit) \\\hline
4MB& 0.289& 1.39 &2 & .005 &.006\\\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a `\rule` of zero width and the desired height; however, I would like to suggest you the use of the [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package to build your tables (this implies giving up on vertical rules, but the result is much better). Below an example with and without `booktabs`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Some values}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}*{6}{c}@{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{L2 Unit} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{SUB} \\ 
\cmidrule(r){2-3}\cmidrule(l){4-6} 
Unit & $E^{\text{Dyn}}_{\text{L2}}$ &  $P^{\text{SUP}}_{\text{L2}}$ 
  & Number & $E^{\text{Dyn}}_{\text{SUB}}$ & $P^{\text{SUP}}_{\text{SUB}}$ \\
Size & (unit) & (unit) & ($N$) &(unit) & (unit) \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-3}
\cmidrule(lr){4-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-5}\cmidrule(l){6-6}
4MB & 0.289 & 1.39 & 2 & .005 & .006\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Some values}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c||c|c|c|}
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{c||}{L2 Unit} &  \multicolumn{3}{c|}{SUB} \\ \cline{2-6} 
\rule{0pt}{14pt}Unit & $E^{\text{Dyn}}_{\text{L2}}$&  $P^{\text{SUP}}_{\text{L2}}$ &  Number  &$E^{\text{Dyn}}_{\text{SUB}}$ &$P^{\text{SUP}}_{\text{SUB}}$ \\
Size & (unit) & (unit) &  ($N$) &(unit) & (unit) \\\hline
4MB& 0.289& 1.39 &2 & .005 &.006\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]